# Detect if user discarded message

Tags: android, email

I'm writing an application and I have a feedback screen. When the user presses submit button, it takes him to the default email client and prefills the email address, subject etc. ("mailto:")

When the user presses Send, my application appears and I thank the user for giving feedback.

However, how can I tell if the user has pressed the Discard button and did not send the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, how can I tell if the user has pressed the Discard button and did not send the email?

You can't.

Comment: what if I must, any idea on how can i fetch that

Comment: @NixitPatel: As I wrote, you can't. The user has complete freedom to change the email, change the recipients, or abandon sending the email.